# QSize size = desktopRect.size() * qreal(0.9); What does it mean?

Tags: c++, qt

Just watching some [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-browserwindow-cpp.html) from qt documentation and kind of stacked on this line of code:

```
QSize size = desktopRect.size() * qreal(0.9);
```

especially why do we need qreal(0.9) here? I know what qreal does but in this very situation I have no idea about purpose of this chunk of code.

Comment: `qreal` is either `double` or `float`. This way the literal `0.9` is converted to the optimal format for the target platform.

Comment: The `sizeHint()` function returns the desired size for a widget. These can be used in layouts for example. This code tells the desired size is just 90% of the size of the available desktop size.